# what is APC internal debugging?

Tags: php, apc

I got a prompt with `Enable internal debugging in APC [no]:`. While installing APC.

> - what is APC internal debugging?
> - Is is better to keep it enabled?

Tried to do a search but couldn't find an answer!

Comment: Take the default value (no). If you don't know what it is, you're likely not to need it. Until you need it and then you know what it is.  And now you know that you can enable it by installing the package. Sounds fair?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This message comes from the pear package of APC. If you set it, APC will be configured with the `--enable-apc-debug` flag, which means the macro `__DEBUG_APC__` is set in the C source code.

This macro will add additional printfs about APC's internal state. Naturally, these are only useful in a testing environment, and should never be activated on a public webserver.

Unless you're editing APC's source code, or tracking down an extremely low-level problem in APC (which is unlikely), you should answer no. You can just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.